# Do database CRUD operations dictate whether and application should be one-way or two-way binding?

Tags: database, reactjs, angular2, data-binding

I am confused (easily done).   To me model is the data from the database sent back as JSON.

When I think of that in an Angular context, when two-way binding is configured, it makes me think the framework is watching/polling the database so that when some other user/process/etc. updates the database, the other user(s) will see the changes in x number of milliseconds.  Is that right?

One way binding makes me think it is just like a regular webpage now.  I fetch a page and it is updated like it always has been.  I have to press a button or some other event to get it to go back to the server and update the webpage, just like I always have with regular old JavaScript and no library (though I use jQuery a lot).

Do I misunderstand these?  Why would I bother with one-way binding, if I am correct?  I could always do that, so is one-way binding meant to be used with a database that is updated often?  Facebook uses it so it seems I am way off.

(I understand how view and model are connected to each other in Angular.  I 
 don't know if the application that uses the database with a lot of CRUD will dictate I need two-way.  Timing issues, etc. aside.)

Comment: Related: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-two-way-data-binding-being-dropped-in-Angular-2-If-Angular-2-0-only-supports-1-way-data-binding-wasnt-2-way-binding-a-major-feature-of-Angular-1-Does-this-imply-that-somehow-2-way-binding-in-Angular-1-wasnt-a-useful-feature#

Comment: Your confusion seems to come from conflating the model and the database. They're not the same thing, and are only tangentially related if at all.

Comment: @cHao The model is what is holding the data or is a representation of it, an instance of it, or however someone wants to define it.  I typically get that data and fill the model from a database.  In my question, I wanted to know if the watcher was "watching" the database via Ajax for changes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I actually found that one, but it is hard to tell if they are correct sometimes, so I thought I'd ask here.  Thanks for the link.  I will reread.

Comment: @johnny: That's the conflation i'm talking about. Binding concerns the view and the model. It doesn't concern the database, unless you yourself involve it. That's a whole separate thing.